# What in-game retailer bonuses are available for Final Fantasy XIII-2?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'd like to be able to acquire the bonuses on the after-market to sate the completionist in me but Square-Enix has decided to add in-game pre-order bonuses and other retailer incentives for *Final Fantasy XIII-2*, and I'm having trouble keeping track of them all.

What retailer bonuses are available that can only be acquired by bonus/redemption codes (like pre-orders)?

Comment: I'm voting to close your question as "Too localized" Mark. After the game has been released this question will no longer be relevant, thus it is too localized in time. Furthermore, depending on the region / where you pre-order it from there will also be differences, which is also too localized.

Comment: @Wipqozn The purpose of Stack Exchange is to adapt to rapidly changing events and specific situations: just because a question is localized doesn't make it too localized for Stack Exchange. I've revised the question to be about in-game retailer bonsues in general, however, to address the fact that you can no longer get pre-order bonsues now that the game is released.

Comment: Your change addresses my concerns.

Comment: shouldn't it be tagged final-fantasy-11 since 13-2=11? :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Final Fantasy Wikia had a list of all DLC](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Final_Fantasy_XIII-2_Downloadable_Content), including in-game retailer bonuses, but it turns out most of the retailer bonuses were timed exclusives and are available for purchase, at least in North America:

#### Weapons

- **Seraphic Wing<sup>NA, JP</sup>:** PSN/Xbox Live purchase<sup>NA</sup>, preorder from Lawsons or HMV
- **Genji Bow<sup>NA</sup>:** PSN/Xbox Live purchase, preorder from Gamestop  (if a Power-up Rewards member)
- **Calamity/Catastrophe Blade<sup>ALL</sup>:** PSN/Xbox Live purchase<sup>NA</sup>, preorder from Square-Enix online<sup>ALL</sup>
- **Muramasa<sup>NA, EU</sup>:** PSN/Xbox Live purchase<sup>NA</sup>, preorder from Amazon.co.uk<sup>EU</sup>, bundled with Nordic edition<sup>EU</sup>

#### Costumes

- **Summoner's Garb<sup>ALL</sup>**: PSN/XBox live purchase<sup>NA, JP</sup>, Preorder from Gamestop (if a Power-up Rewards member) or EBgames<sup>NA</sup>, Preorder from GAME.co.uk or bundled with Nordic edition<sup>EU</sup>
- **Battle Attire<sup>ALL</sup>**: PSN/XBox live purchase<sup>NA, JP</sup>, Preorder from GAME.co.uk or bundled with Nordic edition<sup>EU</sup>

#### Accessories

- **Diva Mic and Diva Headphone<sup>JP</sup>:** Included with "Yakusoku no basho"  single
- **Goddess' Bangle and Goddess' Earrings<sup>JP</sup>:** Included with mini-soundtrack
- **Stiltzkin's Journal and Durable Stiltzkin's Journal<sup>JP</sup>:** Included with *Famitsu Weekly* Issue #1203

#### Monsters

- **Omega<sup>ALL</sup>:**  PSN/XBox live purchase<sup>NA, JP</sup>, Preorder from Amazon.com<sup>NA</sup>, Preorder from GAME.co.uk or bundled with Nordic edition<sup>EU</sup>

---

#### Notes

<sup>ALL</sup>: Available in all regions
<sup>EU</sup>: Available for the European/PAL region
<sup>JP</sup>: Available for the Japanese/Asian region
<sup>NA</sup>: Available for the North American region

Answer (score 4):

> - Head over to GameStop to score an alternate costume for Serah.
> - Amazon is offering an exclusive boss battle against Omega in the coliseum. After defeating him, you can enlist Omega as one of your allied monsters.
> - Best Buy is giving away the Final Fantasy XIII Episodei novella

Source:  [Final Fantasy XIII-2 Pre-Order Bonuses Revealed](http://www.gameinformer.com/b/news/archive/2011/10/03/final-fantasy-xiii-2-preorder-bonuses-revealed.aspx)

Edit:  Amazon's also offering [$20 credit](http://hawtwired.com/blogs/news/archive/2012/01/31/998.aspx).

Comment: I'll update this question when my copy arrives from Amazon UK.