# What are the various promotional versions of Mass Effect 3 (i.e., Gamestop, Best Buy, etc.)?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'd like to know what "promotional" versions of Mass Effect 3 are out there. I know in the past stores like Gamestop, Best Buy, Target, etc. have stocked copies of games for purchase/preorder that include codes for various in-game gear/skins/maps/etc. So what's out there?

Comment: This may be "too localized" for the site, but there's a good table here: http://www.gamemarshal.com/content/20120226135432/mass-effect-3-editions-and-bonuses-comparison.html that includes the various retailer preorder bonuses.

Comment: @agent86 I don't understand how this question is closed as too localized but [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49134/what-in-game-retailer-bonuses-are-available-for-final-fantasy-xiii-2) question, which is basically the same thing worded differently (for a different game), has 6 upvotes.

Comment: I don't really understand how this is "too localized" either. There are frequently stores or sites (like Amazon) that include specific, vendor-based bonuses on all purchases, even outside of preorders. I know games like Gears of War 3, Deus Ex: Human Revolution, and other AAA games did and do this hence the reason I wanted to know what ME3 has going on in this area. For future reference, how do I phrase this question to actually get an appropriate answer instead of a question closure?

Comment: @Adanion, the community as a whole makes decisions about what they believe is on or off topic.  They sometimes don't always align with their past decisions :)  In this case, 5 people decided this was too localized. If you'd like to discuss whether or not we should allow a particular type of question, you might want to consider posting a question over on the [meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/) site, which is where policy questions such as this are decided.

Comment: @agent86 No thanks, I don't feel like making a post that will most likely be downvoted by the same hypocritical people that one minute say, "If a question is easily googleable, a list question, unlikely to help others, etc. then it should be closed" and then the next minute upvote questions that fall into the same category.

Comment: @Adanion, in both cases, the votes you see represent a very small percentage of the Gaming community. An apparent conflict between questions isn't at all uncommon, and usually means asking a meta question can be helpful to resolve the issue. Sure, some people may downvote the question or an answer that matches your perspective ... but the community as a whole will still have a chance to hear your thoughts, and it may be that the community supports you, and the meta question will attract enough votes to reopen this question. If not, at least the discussion will be more visible.